# How to enable virtualenv inside SConstruct?

Tags: python, scons

I need to run scons with `--enable-virtualenv` argument to make the third party python scripts called in SConstruct to work. Would like to know if I can achieve the same result by add some config in `SConstruct` instead of using command line argument?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely you don't actually need to use --enable-virtualenv.

Assuming you run them via:

`scriptname arguments`

You can just include the full path to that script

`/home/user/my_virtualenv/bin/scriptname arguments`

Or if you use python to run it via:

`python scriptname arguments`

You can run it as:

`/home/user/my_virtualenv/bin/python scriptname arguments`

Or if it's none of these, please explain why any of the above aren't working?